# SSL connection to remote server in Grails

Tags: grails, ssl, netty

I need to develop a web-application using Grails. Application server is tomcat. 
This web application gets data from a remote Netty server through SSL connection. 
As this is my first grails app, I need some guidance how to connect and fetch data from remote servers in Grails. I'll be using self signed certificates, and I'm familiar with keystores and truststores. 
Thanks in advance for tips and guidance.

Comment: What have you tried?? What didn't work about what you have tried? What problems are you having? As it stands this question is far too broad for a good answer.

Comment: No research efforts in your question...

Comment: As I indicated earlier,its my first grails app.I've been studying grails during this time,now I understand Controllers, Domain classes, views and Services.I hope I'll find the solution but time  left is short.I have made views,controller for the domain Class "Server". Now I have a list of servers in a table. For each server there is a host and a port number.There is also a button "Connect" next to each server. On clicking the button, grails must connect to the server thru SSL.I don't understand where to create classes for socket connections. Any hint from you can help me a lot. Thanx